# Delphi XE2 Installation fails to download required files due to connection issues

Tags: delphi-xe2

I am trying to install Delphi XE2 and it refuses to download the required files due to connection issues.

There is no issues with my connection and I have turned off all antivirus etc.

We are licensed users as well.

Does anyone know how to install Delphi XE2?

[image: Delphi Error Message]

Comment: Embarcadero offers free support for installation related issues. Open a ticket with them.

Comment: Yes I know Embarcadero offers support for installation issues. But instead of waiting a week for them to reply I thought I would try my luck here. Time is money so better to cover all bases!

Comment: XE2 is over a decade old, what makes you think the installation files are still available online? Instead of using the Web/Online installer, you should use the ISO/Offline installer, which has all of the necessary files embedded in it.

Comment: Pretty sure all their installers download files from the web. The installer has worked in the 2 years as I have successfully installed it in the past.

Comment: Please contact Embarcadero

Comment: @Shane By definition, only the [Web/Feature installer](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Feature_Installer) downloads files from online, whereas the [ISO/Offline installer](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Offline_Installer) does not. There are situations where the IDE can be installed in environments that don't have Internet access, hence the fully-contained ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the web installers no longer work. You can download the ISO images from this link. Barnsten ad Emarcadero partners it would seem and make the installations available for download.

https://www.barnsten.com/rad-studio-installation-links-iso-and-webinstallers/?fbclid=IwAR1kadFKNhot8oIZyxEI0po_cFdAmC_74Mws0dwi_mgXtiDw1HwFnxWXF6g